# SQL Server: query to aggregate considering minimum quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a stored procedure in SQL Server in order to aggregate customer orders (ordered by date) of the same article until they reach a minimum quantity value.

As an example:

```
Article 1: 
CustomerOrder1: 2
CustomerOrder2: 9
CustomerOrder3: 12
CustomerOrder4: 2
CustomerOrder5: 3
CustomerOrder6: 5
CustomerOrder7: 3
CustomerOrder8: 4
```

Let's say there is a minimum quantity of 10 pieces, that can be different for each article.

The stored procedure should populate two tables.

The table of production orders:

```
ProductionOrder1: 2+9 = 11
ProductionOrder2: 12
ProductionOrder3: 2+3+5 = 10
ProductionOrder4: 3+4 = 7
```

The table of link between CustomerOrders and ProductionOrders:

```
ProductionOrder1 - CustomerOrder1
ProductionOrder1 - CustomerOrder2
ProductionOrder2 - CustomerOrder3
ProductionOrder3 - CustomerOrder4
ProductionOrder3 - CustomerOrder5
ProductionOrder3 - CustomerOrder6
ProductionOrder4 - CustomerOrder7
ProductionOrder4 - CustomerOrder8
```

The same action should be done for all the other articles.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Can you please provide a sample code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so, roughly:

1. Create a table variable with ArticleId, CustomerOrderId, Amount, ProductionOrderId and copy CustomerOrders into it. This table will contain the "links" later.
2. Create a table variable for ProductionOrders, the first result table.
3. Create a variable @productionOrderId.
4. Create a cursor which loops over the articles, getting Id and MinQuantity.
5. Create a second cursor which loops over the copied CustomerOrders with ArticleId x from the outer cursor, getting Quantity.
6. Add the quantity to a variable @sum and update the copied CustomerOrders with @productionOrderId (use "WHERE CURRENT OF " as condition & declare the cursor as "FOR UPDATE").
7. If @sum is >= MinQuantity, increase @productionOrderId by 1, create an entry in ProductionOrders with @productionOrderId and the sum. Reset @sum to 0.
8. If your inner loop is finished, repeat the actions from step 6 if @sum > 0.

A cursor looks like so:

```
declare @articleId int;

declare ArticleCursor cursor for
select Id, ...
  from Articles
 where ...

open ArticleCursor;
fetch next from ArticleCursor into @articleId, ...
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin

  -- Inner cursor goes here ...

  fetch next from ArticleCursor into @articleId, ...
 end

close ArticleCursor;
deallocate ArticleCursor;
```

The inner cursor could look something like this (see different cursor declaration with "FOR UPDATE"):

```
declare OrderCursor cursor for
select Id, Amount
  from CustomerOrders
 where ArticleId = @articleId
   for update;

open OrderCursor;
fetch next from OrderCursor into @orderId, @amount;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin

  -- More logic here ...

  update CustomerOrders
     set ...
   where current of OrderCursor;

  fetch next from OrderCursor into @orderId, @amount;
 end

close OrderCursor;
deallocate OrderCursor;
```

Comment: Hi IngoB, thanks for the reply. Can you please provide a sample code? I'm not really experienced with cursors, so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. :)